# Build ffmpeg in ijkplayer

Tags: android, ffmpeg, android-ndk

I am trying to do a build of ffmpeg inside ijkplayer and following this link to do a manual install https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer. I downloaded the ndk and setup the path and setup the path for sdks and then compiling ffmpeg.

previously, it shows to use ndk9 or later and found out from an post to change to 
**do-compile-ffmpeg.sh** from **compile-ffmpeg.sh**. I changed the file according to ndk-11 now its showing me the below line to specify the architechture. Where to mention that architecture.

```
./do-compile-ffmpeg.sh
 ====================
 [*] check env 
 ====================
 build on Darwin x86_64
 ANDROID_SDK=/username/Library/Android/sdk
 ANDROID_NDK=/Users/username/Documents/android-ndk-r11c
 You must specific an architecture 'arm, armv7a, x86, ...'.
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the do-compile-ffmpeg.sh script [here](https://github.com/bbcallen/ijkplayer/blob/fc70895c64cbbd20f32f1d81d2d48609ed13f597/ios/tools/do-compile-ffmpeg.sh#L7), it looks like the arch is the first argument. Depending on what architecture you're building for, you would call the script like so:

```
./do-compile-ffmpeg.sh <your arch>
```

To build for arm, do this:

```
./do-compile-ffmpeg.sh arm
```

Answer (score 0):

```
./init-android.sh
cd android/contrib
./compile-ffmpeg.sh clean
./compile-ffmpeg.sh all
```

You must specific which architecture you want to compile,you can also use this already compile done.

```
compile 'tv.danmaku.ijk.media:ijkplayer-armv7a:0.5.1'
compile 'tv.danmaku.ijk.media:ijkplayer-armv5:0.5.1'
compile 'tv.danmaku.ijk.media:ijkplayer-arm64:0.5.1'
compile 'tv.danmaku.ijk.media:ijkplayer-x86:0.5.1'
compile 'tv.danmaku.ijk.media:ijkplayer-x86_64:0.5.1'
```

For detail you can visit https://github.com/Bilibili/ijkplayer